# File isn't recognized ERROR "Call to a member function store() on null" on Laravel file upload

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, datatables

I'm using Laravel, Ajax with Datatables to manage my info, everything was working fine but i need to upload files to it.
But i'm getting Call to a member function store() on null.

Here's the code of the controller functions (post and fetch):

```
    function postdata(Request $request)
    {
        $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [

            'referencia'  => 'required',
            'tipo_equipo'  => 'required',
            'tipo_servicio'  => 'required',
            'id_reporte'  => 'required',

        ]);

        $error_array = array();
        $success_output = '';
        if ($validation->fails())
        {
            foreach($validation->messages()->getMessages() as $field_name => $messages)
            {
                $error_array[] = $messages;
            }
        }
        else
        {

            if($request->get('button_action') == 'update')
            {


                $servicio = Servicio::find($request->get('servicio_id'));
                $servicio->referencia = $request->get('referencia');
                $servicio->tipo_equipo = $request->get('tipo_equipo');
                $servicio->tipo_servicio = $request->get('tipo_servicio');
                $servicio->id_reporte = $request->get('id_reporte');
                $servicio->imagen_inicio = $request->file('imagen_inicio')->store('public/img/servicio');
                $servicio->imagen_fin = $request->get('imagen_fin');
                $servicio->pdf_reporte = $request->get('pdf_reporte');
                $servicio->save();
                $success_output = '<div class="alertaTables alert alert-success">Servicio Actualizado</div>';
            }
        }
        $output = array(
            'error'     =>  $error_array,
            'success'   =>  $success_output
        );
        echo json_encode($output);
    }

    function fetchdata(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->input('id');
        $servicio = Servicio::find($id);

        $output = array(
            'id_usuario' => $servicio->id_usuario,
            'id_cliente' => $servicio->id_cliente,
            'referencia' => $servicio->referencia,
            'tipo_equipo' => $servicio->tipo_equipo,
            'tipo_servicio' => $servicio->tipo_servicio,
            'id_reporte' => $servicio->id_reporte,
            'imagen_inicio' => $servicio->imagen_inicio,
            'imagen_fin' => $servicio->imagen_fin,
            'pdf_reporte' => $servicio->pdf_reporte
        );
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

Here's the code of my script:

```
     $('#servicio_form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('mis-servicios.postdata') }}",
            method:"POST",
            data:form_data,
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data.error.length > 0)
                {
                    var error_html = '';
                    for(var count = 0; count < data.error.length; count++)
                    {
                        error_html += '<div class="alertaTables alert alert-danger">'+data.error[count]+'</div>';
                    }
                    $('#form_output').html(error_html);
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                        $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
                            $(this).remove(); 
                         });
                    }, 5000);
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#form_output').html(data.success);
                    $('#mis-servicios_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();

                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                        $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
                            $(this).remove(); 
                         });
                    }, 5000);
                }
            }
        })
    });



    $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('mis-servicios.fetchdata') }}",
            method:'get',
            data:{id:id},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#id_usuario').val(data.id_usuario);
                $('#id_cliente').val(data.id_cliente);
                $('#referencia').val(data.referencia);
                $('#tipo_equipo').val(data.tipo_equipo);
                $('#tipo_servicio').val(data.tipo_servicio);
                $('#id_reporte').val(data.id_reporte);
                $('#imagen_inicio').val(data.imagen_inicio);
                $('#imagen_fin').val(data.imagen_fin);
                $('#pdf_reporte').val(data.pdf_reporte);
                $('#servicio_id').val(id);
                $('#servicioModal').modal('show');
                $('#action').val('Editar');
                $('.modal-title').text('Editar Servicio');
                $('#button_action').val('update');
            }
        })            
    });
```

And here’s is the code of my blade.php

```
<main class="content">
                <div class="container-fluid p-0">
                    <h1 class="h3 mb-3">Mis Servicios</h1>

                    <br />
                    <table id="mis-servicios_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" style="width:100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="background-color: white;">
                                <th>Usuario</th>
                                <th>Cliente</th>
                                <th>Referencia</th>
                                <th>Equipo</th>
                                <th>Servicio</th>
                                <th>No. de Reporte</th>
                                <th>Fecha Inicio</th>
                                <th>Fecha Fin</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Acciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div id="servicioModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <form method="post" id="servicio_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Añadir Servicio</h4>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    {{csrf_field()}}
                                    <span id="form_output"></span>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Usuario</label>
                                        <select name="id_usuario" id="id_usuario" class="form-control" disabled>
                                                <option value="">Elige el Usuario</option>
                                            @foreach($useres as $user)
                                                <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Cliente</label>
                                        <select name="id_cliente" id="id_cliente" class="form-control" disabled>
                                                <option value="">Elige el Cliente</option>
                                            @foreach($nombreCliente as $nombreCliente)
                                                <option value="{{ $nombreCliente->id }}">{{ $nombreCliente->nombre_cliente }}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Referencia</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="referencia" id="referencia" class="form-control" readonly/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Tipo de Equipo</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="tipo_equipo" id="tipo_equipo" class="form-control" readonly/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Tipo de Servicio</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="tipo_servicio" id="tipo_servicio" class="form-control" readonly/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>ID Reporte</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="id_reporte" id="id_reporte" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Imagen ID Equipo</label>
                                        <input type="file" name="imagen_inicio" id="imagen_inicio" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Imagen Servicio Terminado</label>
                                        <input type="file" name="imagen_fin" id="imagen_fin" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Reporte en PDF</label>
                                        <input type="file" name="pdf_reporte" id="pdf_reporte" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="servicio_id" id="servicio_id" value="" />

                                    <input type="hidden" name="button_action" id="button_action" value="insert" />
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="action" value="Añadir" class="btn btn-info" />
                                    <button id="cerrarModal" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not allowing you to store the File because the file it's not getting to the server because you're using AJAX to make the request, to send files via AJAX try this:

```
$('#servicio_form').on('submit', function(event){
   event.preventDefault();

   // init formData and get files
   let formData = new FormData($('#servicio_form')[0]);
   let imagenInicio = $('#imagen_inicio')[0].files[0];
   let imagenFin= $('#imagen_fin')[0].files[0];
   let pdfReporte= $('#pdf_reporte')[0].files[0];

   // append files to formData
   formData.append('imagen_inicio', imagenInicio);
   formData.append('imagen_fin', imagenFin);
   formData.append('pdf_reporte', pdfReporte);

   // in AJAX disable contentType, processData and cache
   $.ajax({
      url:"{{ route('mis-servicios.postdata') }}",
      method:"POST",
      dataType:"json",
      data: formData,       // change this and the following options
      contentType: false, 
      processData: false,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
         // your code...
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: @Dharman It really works but the files are not being saved in the folders, the links appear as 404 not found, and if i press on edit button i get this error "Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string."